# Run only failed test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm running a bunch of Scala tests in IntelliJ. One is failing. I can't seem to be able to run just that one failing test (ala Visual Studio) - surely there must be a way to do this in the IDE?

Answer (score 15):

## Rerun Failed Tests Button!

After first running press `Rerun Failed Tests` on toolbar [image] for execute all the tests that failed.

[image]

Also check this **[guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/test-runner-tab.html)** for more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rerun a failed test, I would suggest to first filter the test results to show only failed tests. Then you right click your test(s) you want to rerun and select `Run {testMethodName}` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

An even more easy way is to click on the button right under the green rerun arrow (green arrow with red exclamation mark) to rerun all failed tests.

You can also run only one method by opening your test class, right click on your test method name, and also select `Run {testMethodName}`.

[image]

Comment: weird I don't get those options - is that scala or java in your screenshot?